# How to tell when ubuntu needs a reboot?

Tags: upgrade, reboot

I know I see it in the when I log in to an ubuntu machine that has been patched which needs a reboot, but is there a flag set somewhere in the operation system that says that ubuntu needs to be rebooted?

I've got several hundred devices that I am staggering updates on and I want to get notified of the ones that need to be rebooted. If there's a flag somewhere that is set that would be great and bonus if someone can show me how to find that info with snmp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for the existence of the file `/run/reboot-required`.

The file `/run/reboot-required.pkgs` lists the packages responsible for the reboot requirement.

Comment: Thanks, I was just about to post that, I noticed in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` that `/var/run/reboot-required` was needed.

Comment: And, if one does `cat /run/reboot*`, one sees a list of the packages wanting a reboot.